# HAR entry response content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, har

How can i get the content of a network request in the form of a `HAR` entry in javaScript?

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(function (entries) {
    entries.getContent(function(content, encoding){

    });
}
```